# How to solve 'Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'' this error?

Tags: android, javacompiler

I have tried so many options

- Changed jdk path from recommended to manual path to my **JDK** folder.
- Added `System.properties("java.home")` in gradle dependencies.
- Uninstalled jdk and reinstalled.
- Invalidated & restart.
- Added `java_home=c\:\\program files\\...` path in gradle.properties file.

when checked stack trace I got: `could not find tools.jar: please check valid installation` error

But none of them worked. I still get this error.. struck from last 4 days...

Can anyone suggest anything, please?

Comment: why you are not using recommended jdk from android studio?

Comment: initially i was using recommended jdk.. but recently it started giving me complie error. so i changed to manual jdk path and the error still occurs

Comment: ` it started giving me complie error.` what was that error

Comment: error was app:CompileJavaWithJavac

Answer (score 0):

Enable  use recommended jdk option from Android studio and add below code to your gradle.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so many solutions and finally found the solution for the error `Execution failed for task ':module:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'`

First you need to check the java JRE and JDK version installed in your system. It should be java 11 or higher

If the version is below 11 then update that version and your problem will be resolved.

if you want to know current java JDK and JRE version and want to update it then refer to [this link](https://linuxhint.com/check-update-java-version-ubuntu/)